# Virtual Environments: python -m venv VS echo layout python3

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm fairly new to python, but have built a few small projects. I have been taught, and have always used, the following commands to start a virtual environment: `echo layout python3 > .envrc` and then `direnv allow`.

What are the differences or advantages to using `python -m venv <virtualenv name>` versus `echo layout`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those two commands do entirely different things.

## `venv`

The `python -m venv <env_name>` command [*creates* a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) as a subdirectory full of files in your filesystem.  When it's done, a new virtual environment is sitting there ready for you to activate and use, but this command doesn't actually *activate* it yet.

Activating the virtual environment so you can *use* it is a separate step.  The command to do this depends on which operating system and which shell you're using (see the "Command to activate virtual environment" table in the docs linked above).

The activation command alters only your *current* command-line shell session.  This is why you have to re-activate the virtual environment in every shell session you start.  This kind of annoyance is also what `direnv` exists to solve.

## `direnv` and `.envrc`

### First, about that `echo` command...

In both MS-DOS and Unix / Linux (and presumably recent versions of Macintosh), `echo layout python3` just emits a string `"layout python3"`.

The `>` redirects the `echo` command's output to a file, in this case `.envrc`.  The redirection creates the file if it doesn't already exist, and then replaces its contents (if any) with that string.  The end result is a file in your current working directory containing just:

```
layout python3
```

### The `.envrc` file, and `direnv allow`

`.envrc` is a config file used by the `direnv` application.  Whenever you `cd` into a directory containing a `.envrc` file, `direnv` reads it and executes the `direnv` instructions found inside.

`direnv allow` is a security feature.  Since malicious `.envrc` files could be hidden almost anywhere (especially in world-writable directories like `/var/tmp/`), you could `cd` into a seemingly innocent directory and get a nasty surprise from someone else's `.envrc` land mine.  The `allow` command specifically white-lists a directory's `.envrc` file, and apparently un-lists it if it discovers the `.envrc` file has changed since it was `allow`ed.

### Finally, back to `direnv`

I don't use `direnv`, but [`layout <language>`](http://direnv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/direnv-stdlib/#layout-type) is a `direnv` command to adjust your environment for developing in *language*, in this case activating a Python 3 virtual environment.  The docs hint that it's more "helpful" than just that, but they don't go into any detail.  (Also, you could have written your own `direnv` function called `python3` that does something completely different.)

The goal of all that is to automatically enable your Python virtual environment as soon as you `cd` into its directory.  This eliminates one kind of human error, namely forgetting to enable the virtual environment.  For details, see Richard North's "[Practical `direnv`](https://rnorth.org/practical-direnv)", especially the "[Automatic Python `virtualenv` switching](https://rnorth.org/practical-direnv#automatic-python-virtualenv-switching) section.

## (Dis-)Advantages and Opinions

If that's the kind of mistake you've made frequently, *and* you trust that the `direnv` command will never fall prey to a malicious `.envrc` file (or otherwise "helpfully" mess up something you're working on), then it might be worth it to you.

The biggest down-side I see to `direnv` (aside from the security implications) is that **it trains you to forget about a vital step** in using Python virtual environments... namely, actually *using* the virtual environment.  This goes double for any other "help" it silently provides without telling you.  (The fact that I keep putting "help" in quotes should suggest what I think of utilities like this.)

If you ever find yourself working somewhere `direnv` isn't installed, the odds are good that you'll forget to activate your virtual environments, or forget whatever else `direnv` has been doing for you.  And the odds are even better that you'll have forgotten *how* to do it.

Comment: What an awesome answer. Thanks Kevin. Given your opinion on "helpful" utilities like `direnv`, do you recommend sticking to using python's stdlib venv? Do you see any advantages to possibly using `virtualenv`? From my reading/research, I don't see very many other options for virtual environments, other than python's venv, direnv, and virtualenv.

Comment: @JuanathanCruz: I don't get to use more recent versions of Python very much, so I haven't been able to use the new `venv`.  It seems _very_ similar to the older `virtualenv` (many command-line options are identical), although I don't know whether the Python standard library adopted and renamed `virtualenv` or just mostly-copied it.  I would only recommend switching to the older `virtualenv` if it solved some problem that you can't work around with the `venv` you're already using.